# TensorFlow How to Initialize Global Step

Tags: python, tensorflow

So I'm trying to run a training session, and when I do I get this error when trying to run my algorithm (when I use `tf.train.get_global_step()`):

`ValueError: global_step is required for exponential_decay.`

For some reason, `tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()` doesn't exist for me, I'm not sure if that's because it's a removed method or what. I updated TensorFlow and everything I'm up to date.

I've dug around the documentation and there's nothing about it. To run I'm using `tf.app.run()` with a main function.

Is there another way to initialize the global step variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although [`tf.train.get_or_create_step()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/get_or_create_global_step) is perfectly fine, here is another solution:

```
g_step = tf.get_variable('global_step', trainable=False, initializer=0)

learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(0.1, g_step)
tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss=loss, global_step=g_step)
```

Create an untrainable variable that initializes with zero and passes it to the Optimizer.

If you need global_step later use [`tf.train.global_step()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/global_step):

```
sess = tf.Session()
# Initialize the variable
sess.run(g_step.initializer)
print('global_step: %s' % tf.train.global_step(sess, g_step))
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the reason this function wasn't showing up was because I actually hadn't been on the newest version of TensorFlow even though it was telling me I was completely up to date.

Seen Here:

[image: seen here]

So all I did to fix it was uninstall tensorflow, then install from the actual link I don't have it anymore, but a quick google search would suffice.